# How is type inferred where return type is also upper and lower bound for method parameters

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-inference

Lets suppose we have the following code:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}

public static <T> T testMe(List<? super T> list1,List<? extends T> list2) {
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    List<C> listC = new ArrayList<>();
    // All three variants are possible:
    A a=testMe(listB, listC);
    B b=testMe(listB, listC);
    C c=testMe(listB, listC);
}
```

The question is about `public static <T> T testMe(List<? super T> list1,List<? extends T> list2)`. How does the compiler determine the `T` type if if have three classes:`A,B,C,`? This question arose when I analysed `Collections.copy`.

Comment: If all three variants are possible, doesn't mean that `T` has to be resolved to `C`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is inferring the type `C` for the type parameter `T` in all 3 cases.

It is the [most specific type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) that fits the constraints.

> [T]he inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments.

For the first 2 statements,

```
A a = testMe(listB, listC);
B b = testMe(listB, listC);
```

Both `B` and `C` match, because a `List<B>` matches `List<? super B>` and `List<C>` matches `List<? extends B>`, and a `List<B>` matches `List<? super C>` and `List<C>` matches `List<? extends C>`.  The compiler chooses the most specific type that matches, `C`.

You could get this to compile with an explicit type parameter, to get the compiler to resolve it to `B`:

```
A a = Super.<B>testMe(listB, listC);
B b = Super.<B>testMe(listB, listC);
```

In the third line, only `C` matches, so that is what the compiler chooses for `T`.

```
C c = testMe(listB, listC);
```

This happens because the variable being assigned is of type `C`, and a `B` can't be assigned to `C`.

Comment: It can be `B` too - not always `C`

Comment: @Bohemian For the first two, it can be `B` explicitly, but without an explicit type parameter, the compiler will choose the most specific - `C`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the signature to require a token for `T`, it quickly becomes obvious what is going on:

```
public static <T> T testMe(Class<T> c, List<? super T> list1, List<? extends T> list2) {
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    List<C> listC = new ArrayList<>();
    A a = testMe(A.class, listB, listC); // compile error
    B b = testMe(B.class, listB, listC); // OK. T == B
    C c = testMe(C.class, listB, listC); // OK. T == C
}
```

The reason this compiles in your example:

```
A a = testMe(listB, listC);
```

is because `T` is inferred as `B` (or `C` - it doesn't matter), but `B` is also an instance of `A`, so an object of class `B` can be assigned to variable of type `A`.

Comment: Out of interest, doesn't adding `Class<T> c` to the signature change the type inference process - would the compiler now have another constraint to use on the type of T?

Comment: @Andy no - it forces the caller to explicitly fix `T` for the call, thus taking away type inference and so demystifying the type bound for a typed method.

Comment: This raises another question (maybe I should post it)... Why does the compiler actually *need* a token in the method's argument list that fixes `T`, in order to raise a compilation error? My point is: I don't understand why `A a = testMe(listB, listC);` initially compiles.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it compiles because `T` is `B`, which can be assigned to an `A` (read my answer)

Comment: Yes, indeed, but my point was why the compiler needed a token to raise a compilation error in this case. (I perfectly understand that T is B which can be assigned to an A). Why does the token make any difference? After all, if T is B or C but the result is assigned to type A, a `List<B>` shouldn't be allowed as the first argument. What I see is that arguments' inference mechanism is not taking the type of the result into account...

Answer (score 0):

From a purely theoretical point of view, why does it matter what the type argument is? The type is not encoded into the compiled bytecode. Its only relevance is whether the compile-time type check passes or not. To that end, if the compiler is able to guarantee that *some* choice of type argument makes the code compile, which one and whether there are more should not be relevant. In the first two cases, there exist multiple types (`B` and `C`) that work; the compiler need not decide on one. In the third case, only one type (`C`) works. In all cases, if the compiler is satisfied that at least one type works, it should let it compile.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler knows at compile time what the type of the Object that you are passing e.g., `List<B>` since generics are a compile-time feature. It can use this information to check for type errors. After it's compiled though, generics are thrown away due to *type erasure* and the code is actually this:

```
 public static Object testMe(List<Object> list1, List<Object> list2) {
    //some code
    return null;
}
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't explain why the compiler treats `T` as type `C` for the call `testMe(listB, listC)`.